# ODP.NET Parameterised Query Not Working

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net

I have tried everything I can find on the internet to get this to work.

I am using VS2013, C#, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess v4 (tried oracle.dataaccess.client v14),oracle 11g.

I understand the following code should work (I know connection disposal, usings etc are missing but I've just stripped it back)

```
public CustDetailsModel SelectCustDetails(string CustCode)
{
    string sql;
    OracleDataReader reader;

    OracleConnection OraConn = OraConnection.GetConnection;

        OraConn.Open();

        sql = "SELECT CUSTOMER, NAME, POSTCODE FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUSTOMER = :CUSTCODE";

        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, OraConn);

        OracleParameter parameter = cmd.CreateParameter();
        parameter.ParameterName = "CUSTCODE";
        parameter.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
        parameter.Value = CustCode;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);

            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            reader.Read();

            return new CustDetailsModel
            {
                Cust = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("CUSTOMER")),
                CustName = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("NAME")),
                CustPostCode = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("POSTCODE")),
            };

}
```

if I replace the parameter with a hardcoded value, it works!

It fails with "Invalid operation against a closed object" because the query has returned no rows.

Could someone please help?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Have you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17062954/error-with-oracledatareader-error-invalid-operation-the-connection-is-closed ?

Comment: @SergeyMalyutin - yes, there is no problem with database connection until I introduce the parameter. I'm wondering if I have the correct version of ODAC for 11gR2.

Answer (score 4):

Have you gone here to download the correct version of ODP.NET?[ODP.NET Home Page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085703.html)

I have used the 12 version and it works for 11gr2.

Go to download and Click here to download ODAC with Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio.

Several things to make sure you have correct.  The oracle client and ODP.NET versions must be the same bit'ness 32 or 64. You cannot cross 32 bit client with 64 bit ODP or vise versa.

If the above is correct then your OK. I suspect you are because the query works hard coded.

Could it be this?
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/208176/Gotcha-sharp-Using-Named-Parameters-with-Oracl

Comment: thanks for the reply. I'm now using the ODP managed driver without success. Again, it is working for all queries that do not contain parameters! I've tried everything I can find on the internet including setting the named parameter flag. Any other help greatly appreciated - thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for this. That link to codeproject provided the answer. In essence "there is an additional property, BindByName, on the OracleCommand object, which must be set to true in order to bind parameters by name" . Aargh !